# Change opacity when ellipse is clicked? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the opacity of my ellipse when it's clicked. So if you click the ellipse, it goes from an opacity of 1 to 0.2, and if you click it again, it switches back.

Currently, my ellipse is using a complex multibinding

```
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FloatToCorConv}">
                                    <Binding Path="FValue" Mode="OneWay" />
                                    <Binding Path="MValue" Mode="OneWay" />
                                    <Binding Path="GId" Mode="OneWay" />
                                    <Binding Source="{x:Static foo:Bar.Instance}" Path="IsLiked" Mode="OneWay" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
```

I have a boolean called `IsRemoved` that is a property like `FValue`, but I'm not sure how I can link this to a mouse click for the opacity to change. I have some other button interactions for my ellipse so far.

```
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                <utils:InteractiveCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
                    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.MouseEnter}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                <utils:InteractiveCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
                    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.MouseLeave}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Consider putting the Ellipse in the Template of a Button. You would then have the Click event and IsMouseOver and IsPressed properties.

Comment: How would I bind the opacity of the ellipse to the click event if that's the case?

Comment: You can't bind a property (that is not a command) to an event. There would have to be some code behind that sets an opacity, either directly on the UI element, or on a view model.

Comment: Or use a ToggleButton, where you could set the Opacity according to the IsChecked property.

Comment: is there no way i can just use the ellipse on its own? OR is there no way...

Comment: Sure. Add EventTriggers for Mouse(LeftButton)Down/Up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This display can be created using a `ToggleButton` with an appropriate `Style` / `ContentTemplate`

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Ellipse
                            x:Name="TheEllipse"
                            Width="64"
                            Height="32"
                            Fill="#0000FF"
                            Stroke="Black"
                            StrokeThickness="2" />

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="TheEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="#550000FF" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```